# Automating Router Firmware upgrade with Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn Selenium and for that I am trying to automate my router using Selenium in Python.

I have successfully logged in to the router with credentials but when its coming to navigating to the "System Tools" I am unable to do that... I tried multiple things like finding with ID, name, Linktext nothing is working.

[Image of the Router inspect element for System Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4eBa.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
browser = driver.get("http://192.168.0.1/")
print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)
username = driver.find_element_by_id("userName")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("admin")
username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
password = driver.find_element_by_id("pcPassword")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("admin")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/menu/ol[53]/li/a/span").click()
```

I want to navigate to the Firmware upload page for which I have to navigate through the "System Tools" > "Firmware Upgrade"
Please help

Comment: Could you be more specific and post your code, the error you are getting and exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @alpha1554 done, please see now.